# why can't yield be used in a recursive function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, generator, yield

I am using recursion to get the permutation of a list. Here is what I wrote, but the `yield` version won't work:

```
def test_permutation_rec():
    print "test 2"
    permutation_rec2([1,2,3],[])     
    print "test 1"
    for one in permutation_rec1([1,2,3],[]):
        print "one:",one 

def permutation_rec1(onelist,prelist):  
    if onelist == [] :
        print prelist
        yield prelist

    lenlist= len(onelist)
    for i, oneitem in enumerate(onelist) :
        leftlist = [onelist[j] for j in range(0,lenlist) if j != i]
        permutation_rec1(leftlist,prelist + [oneitem])

def permutation_rec2(onelist,prelist):
    if onelist == [] :
        print prelist

    lenlist= len(onelist)
    for i, oneitem in enumerate(onelist) :
        leftlist = [onelist[j] for j in range(0,lenlist) if j != i]
        permutation_rec2(leftlist,prelist + [oneitem])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_permutation_rec()
```

the result:

```
test 2
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
test 1
```

I think I used `yield` like in [this the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python/104436#104436).

Can anyone tell me why `yield` doesn't take effect?

By the way, `leftlist = [onelist[j] for j in range(0,lenlist) if j != i]`
in `permutation_rec2`, is ugly I think. When the list is big, it creates many temporary lists. How can I improve that?

Comment: For future reference - if you actually need to get permutations, just use the `itertools` module.

Comment: yes . your are right. something like `itertools.permutations([1,2,3])` can somebody find what about the tmplist i have post. Seem  it was not the best solution.

Comment: I review the answer yesterday. sorry may be misclick,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass on the results of the recursive call; each call returns a *generator* and you do have to iterate over that. The answer you linked to certainly loops over the recursive call too.

Add a `for` loop over `permutation_rec1()` and yield each resulting value on to the next caller:

```
def permutation_rec1(onelist, prelist):  
    if not onelist:
        yield prelist

    lenlist = len(onelist)
    for i, oneitem in enumerate(onelist):
        leftlist = [onelist[j] for j in range(lenlist) if j != i]
        for res in permutation_rec1(leftlist, prelist + [oneitem]):
            yield res
```

If you are using Python 3.3 or newer, you can use the new [`yield from` generator delegation syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator):

```
def permutation_rec1(onelist,prelist):  
    if not onelist:
        yield prelist

    lenlist = len(onelist)
    for i, oneitem in enumerate(onelist):
        leftlist = [onelist[j] for j in range(lenlist) if j != i]
        yield from permutation_rec1(leftlist, prelist + [oneitem])
```